# Cordova: duplicate <uses-sdk> in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

I configure the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in the `config.xml` as follows:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="22" />
```

But when i build my app with cordova, there a two  tags in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Where does the version 21 come from?

Any help appreciated, thanks
Angela

Answer (score 0):

one is the one you did in config.xml and one is from the gradle build file..you should match the minSDK in the config.xml file with the one set in your gradle app build file, its found in the android config gradle block.. Once you make them match you will no longer have two minSDk declarations in your manifest file

Comment: you mean in build-extras.gradle file? because all other files are generated while building the app. i added the following to build-extras.gradle. defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        maxSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }still got 2 entries in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: I found out that as soon as i define a plugin in 'config.xml'. The tag <uses-sdk> occurs twice in 'AndroidManifest.xml'.

Comment: Finally i found the problem. We also have a self-implemented plugin which had a sdkdefinition in plugin.xml.  Once i removed it there was only 1 uses-sdk definition in AndroidManifest.xml